# Method for changing classes in Listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created a tabbed view with four tabs and attached four listviews to the tabs.  I have created separate classes with the list views in them and I now want to add a activity to the list view

```
public class l2 extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
    String[] names = new String[] { "Accrington Stanley", "Aldershot Town", "Barnet", "Bradford City", "Burton Albion", "Bury", "Cheltenham Town", "Chesterfield", "Crewe A", "Gillingham", "Hereford Utd", "Lincoln City", "Macclesfield T", "Morecombe", "Northampton T", "Oxford Utd", "Port Vale", "Rotherham Utd", "Shrewsbury T", "Southend Utd", "Stevenage", "Stockport C", "Torquay Utd", "Wycombe W"};
    // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
    // appear in the ListView
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, names));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    names = new intent().setClass(this, Bradford.class);
    // Get the item that was clicked
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String keyword = o.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
```

}

I have 24 teams in the listview and I have created a class for each one, but how can I make it so that when the user selects the team in the list it goes to the class in question i.e bury,bradfdord accrington ect.......?

What method should I use  and how do I implement it.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly

you can use startACtivity(names);

Comment: Would that start a class on its own

Comment: Yes tha will start the activity